# Mysql2 throws errors on invalid dates

Tags: ruby, mysql2

I have an issue with Mysql2 when it tries to get an invalid date (e.g. 2012-00-25).
For example:

require 'mysql2'

db = Mysql2::Client.new(....)

results = db.query(query)

results.each do |row|

..

..

end

If the first record has an invalid date, mysql2 will throw an error and it will stop in that point.

How could I handle it correctly (to catch the error and recover the wrong data)?

I don't have control of the source data.

Thanks in advance,

**My solution**:

I solved the issue adding :cast => false and parsing the date column

db.query(query,:cast => false)

results.each do |row|

..

begin

```
Date.parse(time)
```

rescue

```
# if date is wrong then set the date field

time = "1900-01-01 00:00:00"
```

end

..

end

Comment: the error message is Invalid date: 2012-00-25 17:30:00